# How to set Parameter in WorkItem to be reached within BPMN Process in jbpm-WorkBench

Tags: jbpm, bpmn, kie, kie-workbench, kie-wb

I have created a custom WorkItem with some parameters, which I have registered in WorkDefinitions.wid file. Then in Business Process I also create Variable Definitions for the entire Process and reference those from WD.wid of my custom WorkItem to those created in BP.

WorkItem execute the code, which takes those parameters from the form after starting the process. For this purpose I use  getParameter()- method;
It looks as follows:

```
public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {

String payload = workItem.getParameter("id") + ... ;
...
manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), null);
}
```

Everything looks and works ok, cause WorkItem will be successfully executed and I get the result (on the server side after executing workItem in BP);
But now I need to get Response after executing POST method with entered parameters. In the code I've created a new variable, which gets parameter from response body and I can see result in the IDE's console, when I execute pure code (without BPMN - process), but I need also register this variable within WorkItem to use it further for the next Task in my BProcess.

SO My Question is: is there something similar to getParameter() - method, but something as setParameter()? How could I register it within WorkItem and how could I get/reach those parameter/variable within BProcess in jbpm (something as global variable I believe).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Javadoc of [WorkItemManager](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/kie-api-javadoc/org/kie/api/runtime/process/WorkItemManager.html) and see the parameters of `completeWorkItem` method. You can pass your results in a map. You will then get those values as output parameters of the task that is being executed and can map them to some process variables so the next task can use them.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it also today, to put HashMap instead of null as second parameter of completeWorkItem(), but how can I reach this variable within BP-model? Should I register the name of HashMap-key in .wid file to my WorkItem as all other parameters? Should I create a new Variable for this parameter  in Variable Definitions of the whole BProcess and then reference to it in the WorkItem-Node as Output Parameter? Could you please describe this process, cause after execution of my process this variable is still empty.

Comment: If you create a work item definition in KIE Workbench, you can see that it will automatically generate code with **Result** variable (`java.util.Map`) under the **results** section. I believe you can get your output parameters from this (although I have not tried it). You just need to map this variable to some process variable and then access it later in some task.

Comment: in fact it will be nothing automatically generated, but with the RESULTS it was right point!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version do you use, but for jBPM 6.3, I used to do the same by defining a custom java workitem with a different execute method definition. For me it looks like this:

```
public Map<String, Object> execute(WorkItem workItem) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    result.put("outputparam", "hello world");
    return result;
}
```

Using this, I can reference the "outputparam" as a Data Output assignment in the workflow Process for my custom service node.

Comment: Sorry, cannot check it right now: is this method references to the method of the class implementation (execute()) or it is just a self-created method. If it is a self-created, should I use it as static within executeWorkItem? Cause I've tried something same today, I mean HashMap, but instead of using it as a separate return method, I've just added HashMap inside executeWorkItem(..) and then added it instead of null to completeWorkItem(..) as follows:

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(..);
    manager.completeWorkItem(workItem.getId(), params);

Comment: Then I tried to reach it within my BProcess, I've registred also the key-name of HashMap by my CustomWorkItem within .wid -file.
But I get no any result to this variable, even after setting it to output by the workItem - task (I mean inside BP-Model) and referencing it to the created variable special for this field in Variable Definitions.
And I use 6.4.-version

Comment: Ah ok, 6.4 is different. The 6.3 required to have an execute(...) method instead of the executeWorkitem(...) and it was returning the map instead of passing it to the completeWorkItem. The usage of the returned values on the process definition side is the same, I belive.